# How can I determine which encoding the file uses before I read the file?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm facing a problem.

A file can be written in some encoding such as `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`, `UTF-32`, etc.

When I read a `UTF-16` file, I use the code below:

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                           new InputStreamReader(
                           new FileInputStream(file), "UTF16"));
```

How can I determine which encoding the file is in before I read the file ?

When I read `UTF-8` encoded file using `UTF-16` I can't read the characters correctly.

Comment: You really can't. Is `\x00\x00\x00\x00` four null-characters (U+00000000) of UTF-8, two null-characters of UTF-16 (big endian?), or one null-character of UTF-32?

Comment: it's like asking: "can i before talking to somebody know what language they speak?"

Comment: Either you have to know in advance, or require something like a BOM.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good way to do that. The question you're asking is like determining the radix of a number by looking at it. For example, what is the radix of `101`?

Best solution would be to read the data into a byte array. Then you can use [String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5b%5d,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) to test it with multiple encodings, most likely to least likely.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Which transformation format applies is usually determined by the first four bytes of the file (assuming a BOM). You cannot see those just from the outside.

Comment: Not even that is necessarily true. There's no mandatory "header" for arbitrary files.

Comment: Of course, but especially with UTF-16 you usually have a BOM or an external declaration of the encoding.

Comment: If you have an external declaration of the encoding, the entire question becomes moot, non?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first few bytes and try to guess the encoding.

If all else fails, try reading with different encodings until one works (no exception when decoding and it 'looks' OK).